# Session revocation for AWS Cognito Federated Identities

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-cognito

I'm using developer identity provider in conjunction with AWS Federated Identities.
Now I'm working on password change use case and unable to find how I can revoke all of user's active sessions.
It's essential to revoke all of current sessions when user changes password.

How it's possible?

Comment: you may logout from the cognito session https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cognito/latest/developerguide/logout-endpoint.html however federated identities are decoupled

Comment: @gusto2, provided link is for user pools, not for federated identities. I do not use user pools.