# How to sign out of an AWS Cognito federated identity session?

Tags: expo, amazon-cognito, federated-identity

It is easy to sign into an AWS Cognito session either via username and password or federated identity using { Auth } from 'aws-amplify' by

```
Auth.signIn({ username: email, password: password})
```

or

```
Auth.federatedSignIn({ provider: 'Google' }); // or 'SignInWithApple' || 'Facebook'
```

and it is easy to sign out of a Cognito session via

```
Auth.signOut();
```

Possibly worth noting that we are using expo-web-browser to launch in-app browser sessions, and not directing out to an external safari / chrome window.

The problem is that the Auth.signOut() call does not revoke the token from the Google / Apple / Facebook session, so whenever `Auth.federatedSignIn({ provider: 'Google' });` is called again, the user is already signed in.

This is suboptimal, because it means that if a user logs in via Google / Facebook / Apple, they lose the ability to sign in using a different Google / Facebook / Apple account.  It also makes it very difficult to debug issues happening on the first login from federated providers, since it will not let the tester change accounts.

Has anyone found a valid solution in the most recent version of Expo? (35 as of time of writing this)

This is a [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52354685/session-revocation-for-aws-cognito-federated-identities), unanswered and not providing a lot of context

This [documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cognito/latest/developerguide/logout-endpoint.html) suggests to call

```
GET https://mydomain.auth.{region}.amazoncognito.com/logout?
client_id={CLIENT_ID}&
logout_uri=https://myclient/logout
```

but I have not had luck with this method in my app when calling

```
fetch('https://{MY_DOMAIN}.auth.us-west-2.amazoncognito.com/logout?client_id={CLIENT_ID}&redirect_uri=exp://127.0.0.1:19000&response_type=code', {
        method: 'GET',
        //Request Type
    })
```

from my logout button

This [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56380865/react-native-remove-expo-cookies) mentions that they were thinking about adding a clear cookies for the expo-web-browser package, but it doesnt look like that ever made it through code review.

Notably, even while on a development server and running `expo r -c` the Federated Auth identity cookies will still push you through without a sign in.

Any suggestions on how to clear out the Google / Facebook / Apple federated login session that Cognito looks at?

Comment: Hi @ShepSims - did you find a way forward on this? We're also using Apple Sign In with Cognito and unsure how to revoke the tokens from Apple on sign out (or user deletion).

Comment: Not yet... it's one of those pesky bugs that has been hanging in our backlog for longer than out team would like to admit

Comment: is there any solution to this problem ?

Comment: Have you ever tried `Auth.signOut({ global: true })` if you are using https://github.com/aws-amplify/amplify-js/blob/main/packages/auth/src/providers/cognito/apis/signOut.ts .